# Why I have this strange CSS behavior on the a:hover tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this custom theme on which I am working: http://www.asper-eritrea.com/

The problem is that when you pass the mouse over a link (for example the title of a post) it changes color to yellow so the text appears invisible.

This happens because it uses these CSS settings (I see it using `FireBug`):

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a, a:hover {
   color: #f1b000;
}
```

But why does it use these CSS settings? This is not a link contained into a list contained itself into an element having class `widget-sidebar`

How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Looks like poor coding to me. I suspect that the second property should have been `.widget-sidebar ul li a:hover {color: #f1b000;)
}

Comment: a:hover means global for anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `CSS` Style to:

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a, .widget-sidebar ul li a:hover {
   color: #f1b000;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The comma separates `complete` selectors. Your code is equivalent to:

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a {
   color: #f1b000;
}
    
a:hover {
   color: #f1b000;
}
```

You need to specify `.widget-sidebar ul li` for *both* parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `CSS` applies to all the links. To restrict to specific, you have to use like below:

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a, .widget-sidebar ul li a:hover {
   color: #f1b000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That `CSS` rule means, select all the links in the `li`'s in the `ul`'s in the `widget-sidebar` and all `a` tags on hover, what you're looking for is:

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a, .widget-sidebar ul li a:hover {
   color: #f1b000;
}
```

This means they will always be yellow, even on hover

Answer (score 1):

You have two selectors. First is `.widget-sidebar ul li a` and second is `a:hover`

Change it to:

```css
.widget-sidebar ul li a, .widget-sidebar ul li a:hover {}
```